# Why isn't $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^kz^{-2k-1}=\sum_{-\infty}^{-1}\frac{z^m}{i^{m+1}}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, laurent-series

I was calculating the Laurent series of $\frac{z}{z^2+1}$ centered in $0$ and that converges for $|z|>3$ when in the middle of my calculations I wondered why the follwing is false:

$$\begin{align} &\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^kz^{-2k-1}=&\left[\text{Let }m=-2k-1<=>k=-\frac{m+1}{2}\right]\\ &=\sum_{m=-\infty}^{-1}(-1)^{-\frac{m+1}{2}}z^m=\\ &=\sum_{-\infty}^{-1}i^{-(m+1)}z^m=\\ &=\sum_{-\infty}^{-1}\frac{z^m}{i^{m+1}} \end{align}$$

When I start doing calculations with this Laurent series, those calculations turned out to be incorrect. Why isn't this a correct manipulation?

Comment: What is the coefficient of $z^{-2}$ in the original series? How about the coefficient of $z^{-2}$ in the final result? Is your transformation $m=-2k-1$ a bijection between the non-negative integers $k$ and the negative integers $m$?

Answer (score 0):

In the first sum an important property is that it only has odd exponentials. As an example the coefficient for $z^{-2}$ is zero and so forth. However this property is not preserved when I do the manipulation $[\text{Let }=−2−1<=>=−\frac{+1}{2}]$ since I get a square root. As an example the coefficient for $z^{-2}$ therefore becomes $\frac{1}{i}\neq0$. A better manipulation would be $m=-k$.

Comment: The thing is that your transformation $m=−2k−1$ is not a bijection between the non-negative integers and the negative integers. In your second sum $m=-1,-3,-5,\ldots$ runs over the negative *odd* integers and not all the negative integers.